# Matlab Only Display One Window At A Time

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Let's say the following is my MatLab command. They are being entered in sequence.

```
I = imread('C:\Documents and Settings\Guest\Desktop\test.jpg');

imshow(I);

imhist(I);
```

After line 2 is executed, MatLab invokes a window displaying the image "I". Line 3 will display the histogram of "I". The histogram will replace the image (in the same window).

What I want to do is:

1. I would like to maintain my image window (let's called it "Figure 1" window)
2. The histogram is invoked in another window ("Figure 2")

Can someone please advise me on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using [`figure`](http://esra.univ-paris1.fr/matlab5/techdoc/environ/matlab20.html)

```
I = imread('C:\Documents and Settings\Guest\Desktop\test.jpg');

figure(1);
imshow(I);

figure(2);
imhist(I);
```

Comment: Also, if you want to you can produce both on the same figure---look up the `subplot` command.